# How to write regex to check if a string contains special character and multiple whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am trying to check if a string contains `^°<>#*~!"§$%?®©¶` and used this approach:

```
string myString = "Test%";
var format = /[^°<>#*~!"§$%?®©¶/g]+/;
let checkIfContains = format.test(myString);
```

But when I use a multiple words, it fails as there is one whitespace. I also checked whitespace and string length after removing whitespaces, but I need a single regex or format to fix the issue. Is it possible to do this in TypeScript or JavaScript?

Comment: Please provide a sample input for which this code is failing

Comment: you have no closing `]` for a start - oh, wait you do ... but you have /g inside the `[]` ... shouldn't that be `[^°<>#*~!"§$%?®©¶]+/g` - and having `^` as the first character after `[` negates the search - so you'll want `[°^<>#*~!"§$%?®©¶]+/g`

Comment: I would suggest back slashing all your special characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, global modifier (/g) should be placed in the very end of regex (but if you just looking for any match it is not nessesary here).
Secondly, `^` symbol right after `[` is treated as a NOT modifier for the set of characters denoted by `[]`, so in this case it should be either prepended by `\` metacharacter, or placed somethere else inside `[]`.

So the correct regex to find any of this characters is:

```js
    const regex = /[\^°<>#*~!"§$%?®©¶]+/;
```

Regex to find any of this characters AND multiple whitespaces is a bit trickier, cause we need to handle several cases here:

1. [whitespace][special character(s)][whitespace]
2. [whitespace][whitespace][special character(s)]
3. [special character(s)][whitespace][whitespace]

Also, there could be some other characters in between

Regex to handle this:

```js
    const regex = /(\s+.*[\^°<>#*~!"§$%?®©¶]+.*\s+|\s+.*\s+.*[\^°<>#*~!"§$%?®©¶]+|[\^°<>#*~!"§$%?®©¶]+.*\s+.*\s+)/;
```

Comment: You rock!.. Many thanks, it seems to work and I will give a try asap and if there is a problem, I will inform you.